# Write the following sequence as a recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction

Write the following sequence as a recurrence relation (with sufficient initial values specified):

$$b_n=1-\frac{1}{2^n} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*$$

I think I am suppose to use induction (e.g. n-1) to prove the recurrence, but I am confused, how?

Comment: There are infinite ways to create a recurrence relation.

Comment: This is just my homework I copied straight out of the book...I believe it wants the form asubn = asubn-1 + ???. (stating asub1 = ???).

Comment: So what is $b_n - b_{n-1}$?  What is $b_1$ or $b_0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT** $\ $ Eliminate $\rm\ 1/2^n\ $ from the equations for $\rm\ b_n,\ b_{n+1}\ $

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote 
$$\frac{1}{2^{n}} = 1 - b_{n}$$
and similarly for the $n-1$ case then you could probably see a relationship between $b_{n-1}$ and $b_n$